# Color of Python Comment Keywords in Latex

Tags: python

if have the following problem.

I have to insert Python Code in Latex.
I copied a nice code for Latex which creates a good looking Python output for my purposes.

Now I have the problem that I defined a certain color for programming keywords like "for, and,..."
But Latex, of course, displays also the and's and for's that I used in the comment section in Python after the # sign in this color.
Is there any way to change this?

Best

Felix

[image]

Comment: Please paste the code here so that others can copy to test. Don't include a screenshot.

Comment: You are missing the definition of the normal comment (only triple quote comments `'''` and `"""` are defined), so you should add `morecomment=[l]\#,%`. However, Python is a language that is defined by default for `listings`, so you don't need this definition at all, remove all this code and just use `\lstset{language=Python}` and you are done.

Comment: and if you do want additional settings that are different from the default then use `\lstset` for this and not `\lstdefinelanguage`, with `\lstset` the extra settings are applied on top of the defaults, whereas with `\lstdefinelanguage` the defaults are discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\lstset`. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{keywords}{RGB}{255,0,90}
\definecolor{comments}{RGB}{0,0,113}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{160,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,150,0}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=Python, 
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, 
        keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
        commentstyle=\color{comments},
        stringstyle=\color{red},
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\color{green},
        keywords=[2]{pow},
        keywordstyle=[2]{\color{orange}},
}

\begin{lstlisting}
#This is a comment with keywords: and or for in range
n = 5
for i in range(0, n): 
    print( pow(i,3) )
#Over and out
\end{lstlisting}    

\end{document}
```

The above code will give you this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there an opportunity to define the style of functions in Python? Functions such as "pow" I would like Latex to display in a bright orange instead of pink. How can I define the function style without changing the pink color of keywords like "import"?

Comment: @Felixx2403 you can use another set of keywords with `keywords=[2]{pow}` and then assign a color to them. I just updated the code.

Comment: Ahh, now I see how the assignment of keywords works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. You can use many sets of kewords with different colors. Just keep adding indexes: `keywords=[n]{name}`.